# iOS: Block property directly set crashes when accessed

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, clang

Consider the following code:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^blockCopy)();
@end

@implementation ClassA

@synthesize blockCopy;

- (void)giveBlock:(void(^)())inBlock {
    blockCopy = inBlock;
}

@end
```

Then use it in a class which has a `strong` property of type `ClassA` called `someA`:

```
self.someA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
[self.someA giveBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"self = %@", self);
}];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.someA.blockCopy();
    self.someA = nil;
});
```

If I run that built `O3` with ARC enabled, on iOS, it crashes during the `self.someA.blockCopy();` call inside `objc_retain`. Why?

Now I realise that people are probably going to say I should be setting it with `self.blockCopy = inBlock` but I did kind of think that ARC should be doing the right thing here. If I look at the assembly (ARMv7) produced from the `giveBlock:` method it looks like this:

```
        .align  2
        .code   16
        .thumb_func     "-[ClassA giveBlock:]"
"-[ClassA giveBlock:]":
        push    {r7, lr}
        movw    r1, :lower16:(_OBJC_IVAR_$_ClassA.blockCopy-(LPC0_0+4))
        mov     r7, sp
        movt    r1, :upper16:(_OBJC_IVAR_$_ClassA.blockCopy-(LPC0_0+4))
LPC0_0:
        add     r1, pc
        ldr     r1, [r1]
        add     r0, r1
        mov     r1, r2
        blx     _objc_storeStrong
        pop     {r7, pc}
```

That is calling `objc_storeStrong` which in turn does a `retain` on the block and a `release` on the old block. My guess is that ARC is not properly noticing it's a block property as I think it should be calling `objc_retainBlock` instead of the normal `objc_retain`.

Or, am I just totally wrong and actually ARC is doing what it documents and I've just read it the wrong way?

Discussion very much welcome on this - I find this to be rather intriguing.

Points to note:

- It doesn't crash on OS X.
- It doesn't crash built `O0`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
- (void)giveBlock:(void(^)())inBlock {
    blockCopy = inBlock;
}
```

You need to copy the block either on assignment or when passed into this function.   While ARC solves the auto-move-to-heap-on-return problem, it does not do so for arguments (can't do to idiosyncrasies of C).

That it doesn't crash in certain environments is merely coincidental;   it won't crash as long as the stack version of the block hasn't been overwritten.   A sure sign of this is when you have a crash that goes away with optimization turned off.   With optimization off, the compiler won't reuse stack memory within any given scope, causing the memory to be "valid" for long after it should be.

---

> I still don't quite understand why it can't do a objc_blockRetain
>   rather than a normal objc_retain, though. The compiler knows the type
>   after all.

I'm pretty sure that the issue is the potential cost of the assignment.   If the block captures a lot of state, including, potentially, other blocks, then the Block_copy() might be really *really* **really** expensive.

I.e. if you had something like:

```
BlockType b = ^(...) { ... capture lots of gunk ... };
SomeRandomFunc(b);
```

... and that implied a Block_copy() merely because of the assignment, it would make it impossible to use blocks consistently without risk of pathological performance issues.  Because there is no way for the compiler to know whether `SomeRandomFunc()` is synchronous or asynchronous, there is no way to manage this automatically (at this time -- I'm sure getting rid of this potential tripwire is desirable).

Comment: I'm just slightly surprised to see it going through a `objc_storeStrong` when assigning though, and it not being able to "do the right thing".

Comment: From what I understand (been a while), there are edge cases that prevent the compiler from emitting code that would "just work" in all cases correctly.   Under ARC, the hard line in the sand requires the compiler to be able to exactly prove that any given code pattern will always work all the time everywhere.   In this case, it can't do that because there are valid uses for stack-only block arguments passed through any given call site (including `objc_storeStrong()`).

Comment: I still don't *quite* understand why it can't do a `objc_blockRetain` rather than a normal `objc_retain`, though. The compiler knows the type after all.

Comment: I like your update, but that's different IMO. That's during a function call. I'm talking about setting to an instance variable of a class. The compiler can know that we're wanting to use it later, unless we set it back to `nil` at the end of the method we set it in, in which case it would `retain` and `release` it which would cancel out and ARC could optimise it out.

Comment: There is certainly room for improvement.  The problem still remains that, even with basic assignment, there may be other code paths that end up using the Block in an unsafe manner.  There are simply a ton of edge cases.   I suspect this will get better over time;  the current behavior is the pattern of least surprise -- it crashes or it works in a predictable amount of time.

Comment: I don't really understand why you need to manually capture `[inBlock copy]` if `blockCopy` property is declared as `copy` already. Isn't the property setter already doing the copy for you?

Comment: @PabloA. They aren't going through the setter in the `giveBlock:` method.